# In Solr Cloud, is QueryElevationComponent mandatory in distributed collection?

Tags: linux, solr

I have collection that is distributed over multiple solr cloud node. To disable uniqueKey in schema, I also disable QueryElevationComponent in solrconfig.xml.

```
<!--
  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>
-->
```

Configuration works fine in undistributed collection (1 shard, 1 rf). But if number of shards*rf are greater than 1, problem occures. When I execute query to distributed collection, than solr throws below exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.createMainQuery(QueryComponent.java:852)
>    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.regularDistributedProcess(QueryComponent.java:721)
>    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.distributedProcess(QueryComponent.java:674)
>    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:345)
>    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:154)

Solr does not complain against indexing. Only querying is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uniqueKey is required. as 
 it will likely 
     make routing in SolrCloud and document replacement in general fail.

Enable your uniqueKey in schema, if you are using solr in cloud mode.

Comment: Yes you're right. The last part of stack (top line on stack trace) is below :

Comment: String keyFieldName = rb.req.getSchema().getUniqueKeyField().getName();
I guess than getUniqueKeyField() returns null and getName() throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Up Vote/accept if you found my answer usefull. thank you